# type mismatch error declaring list of classes

Tags: list, scala, generics, collections

```
  def getValueAndItsType() : List[ (AnyRef, Class[_]) ] = {
    val dataSet1 = ("some string data", classOf[String])
    val dataSet2 = (new Thread(), classOf[Thread])
    val dataSet3 = (new NullPointerException(), classOf[NullPointerException])
    val dataSet4 = (5, classOf[Int])
    val list = List(dataSet1, dataSet2, dataSet3, dataSet4)
    list
  }
```

---

> Type type mismatch;  found   :
>   List[(Any, Class[_ >: Int with NullPointerException with Thread with
>   String])]  required: List[(AnyRef, Class[_])]

---

```
If dataSet4 is removed from List, the compile time error disappears
```

> Please suggest, what is wrong with Class[_]. Isn't it
>   equivalent to Class[?] in java ? I appreciate, if you also suggest
>   correct declaration for doing this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Scala**:

- `Any` is the root of the **Scala** class.
- `AnyRef` is the root of the class of **reference types**, it extends from `Any`.
- `AnyVal` is the root class of all **value types**. it extends from `Any`
- `Null` is a subtype of all **reference types**.
- `Nothing`is a subtype of ***all other types*** including `Null`

So base on your code, you need to extend from `Any`, include `AnyRef: reference types` and `AnyVal: values types`.

```
def getValueAndItsType() : List[ (Any, _ <: Any) ] = {
    val dataSet1 = ("some string data", classOf[String])
    val dataSet2 = (new Thread(), classOf[Thread])
    val dataSet3 = (new NullPointerException(), classOf[NullPointerException])
    val list = List(dataSet1, dataSet2, dataSet3)
    list
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I just updated the question, as it is not accepting dataSet4, that contains a type of Int.

Comment: I thought, anything in scala is a object. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @rits Yes you are right, anything in scala is an object, and [Any](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any) is root class.