# value isAssignableFrom is not a member of Any in scala

Tags: scala, object, types

```
val list = getValueAndItsType()
list.foreach{ e =>
  val data = e._1
  val dataType = e._2
  println( dataType.isAssignableFrom( value.getClass ) )
}

 def getValueAndItsType() : List[ (AnyRef, Class[_]) ] = {
    val dataSet1 = ("some string data", classOf[String])
    val dataSet2 = (new Thread(), classOf[Thread])
    val dataSet3 = (new NullPointerException(), classOf[NullPointerException])
    val dataSet4 = (5, classOf[Int])
    val list = List(dataSet1, dataSet2, dataSet3, dataSet4)
    list
  }
```

As reference to my other question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645424/type-mismatch-error-declaring-list-of-classes). Now, i am getting below compile time error :-

```
value isAssignableFrom is not a member of Any
```

on line `println( dataType.isAssignableFrom( value.getClass ) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List[ (Any, Class[_]) ]` worked.